# How to use compiled wxwidgets with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I'm getting some trouble while trying to use wxwidgets in my project (I'm on linux). It worked well when I was with wxWidget 3.02, but when I tried to use 3.1.0 it stopped to work.

I still have the 3.0.2 (so I can have something working) but I want to use the wxlistctrl::EnableCheckBoxes(), so I get the 3.1.0.

In my CMakeList, I change `FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets REQUIRED)`to `FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets 3.1.0 REQUIRED)`

When i try to `cmake ..`in my build directory, I got the following error:

```
... could NOT find wxWidgets: Found unsuitable version "3.0.2", but required is 
at least `3.1.0`(found
-L/usr/local/lib//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu; ...
```

I know that the library is located at `/usr/local/lib` I tried to ln to the directory, I tried many commands in my cmake, but I don't know how to tell cmake to search in the good library to find th wxWidgets version I want.

I'm pretty sure it's a cmake mistake, but it can be an installation problem too (even if I followed the tutorial  [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started)). More, when I type `gtk-config --version`I got "3.1.1" (that's what I expected as version number, I get the git version)

If anyone has a question or an idea to solve my problem, I would be haappy to read it =)

Thank's!

Comment: can't you use a plain old `wx-config` script to compile you software? Something like `g++ -o <my_binary> `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` <my_source.cpp>?

Comment: Hi! no, I can't, my project is too big to do that. I know that my project is actualy working, I know that wxwidgets  3.1 is working to (thanks to the samples) but my cmake failed to find wxwidgets 3.1

Comment: then if you don't want to use IDE (Anjuta for example), the easiest and simplest solution is to gewt rid of 3.0 and install 3.1.

Comment: I've already installed 3.1 from github (cd build-gtk && ../configure && make && sudo make install), I tried to move 3.0 files from where they are to another location, but hen, cmake only find nothing (thank's for your help btw)

Comment: don't move it anywhere. Uninstall it first, then install 3.1 and then run cmake. I guess the order is important.

Comment: not better, I just have `missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS` (as before, the only difference is that 3.0.2 is no more found =) )

Comment: Did you uninstall 3.0.2 and then install 3.1?

Comment: yes, as you suggested me to do =)

Comment: than I'm out of ideas. Sorry. Try to compile with g++ command I proposed earlier. If that works and the command produced will be using 3.1 and not failing - something weird is going on with the setup. Try to install everything from scratch, slipping wx 3.0.

Comment: It sems that as wxwidget 3.1 is in developpement state, it's not yet compatible with cmake. Other users of wxwidgets use the wx-config script to compile their program

But thank you to have taken some times to reply to me =)

And I'm out of ideas too, so I upvoted your last comment

Comment: did you inspect the CMake module that finds wxWidgets to make sure it looks in right directories?

Answer (score -2):

CMake saying that your minumum version of cmake, `3.0.2`, is lower than the wxWidgets minimum cmake version, `3.1.0`.

Try putting the command: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)`.

That way your minimum cmake version required will be `3.1.0` so it will be fine.